# C# chart Axis anchor - resizing MajorTickMark and MinorTickMark

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I would like to ask you for one stuff. I have Chart, which could be resized. In init state everything looks ok. But when user resize chart, at axis X are ticks resized as well. But I need to stay in init state. I am looking for solution but I have not found.

Thanks in advance for your ideas.
[Init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH96c.png)

[Resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgEP2.png)

Comment: Did you code any properties of the tickmarks??

Comment: What exactly do you think? I am using default Property MajorTickMark and MinotrTickMark and I haven'f found any property to set this.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust size of MinorTickMark according to chart Height or chart Width.

Take a look at this project: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1036182/A-Powerful-Chart-Control

Comment: This link requires a login to an external site. It would be best to post any relevant code in your answer.